# How to get organic search keywords from GA4 API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to retrieve the keyword search terms used in organic searches using the GA4 data API.

Is this possible while using GA4 connected with Google Search Console?

I've been trying to find the dimension parameter with no luck. I think the equivalent in UA was "ga:keyword".

Thanks in advance!
Marta

Comment: why extracting them from GA? Just get them from GSC. GSC has it's own API. https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/searchanalytics/query

Comment: The reason I was trying to get the keywords from GA is that I wanted to cross this information with the number of sessions / conversions in GA, to see which keywords earned more conversions. However, all the information I am reading seems to point to the fact that this information can't be analyzed together. Is that the case, or am I missing something? Thanks a lot

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, this data is not joinable. I'm going into details in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data from GSC is not joined to the GA data when you link GSC to GA. Despite what it seems like, the data is not truly linked/joined. It just makes GSC data be available in GA UI.

First, GSC's data is given to the users and very likely stored in the DB in an aggregated state rather than raw. Second, GSC's data is sampled so strongly that it becomes unjoinable. Even if you look at the global aggregate trends, they don't always match.

You can still relate the data from the two sources though. It will not be able to answer many questions, or give precise answers, but it may give value to a deeper analysis. [This](https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/data-science/how-to-join-google-analytics-and-google-search-console-data) would be a good, simple example of how this data can be used together.